# Surface area of intersection of sphere and off-angle cone (Footprint of satellite)

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, area

A satellite has a telescope looking down at a section of the Earth, so its field of view is a cone with some angle φ. The telescope can slew any direction θ (non-perpendicular to Earth), and doing so will change the surface area in its field of view. What is the equation for that surface area? You can assume that the earth is a sphere of radius $r$ and the satellite is $h$ above the ground.

Here is an illustration of the parameters as well as the surface area in light blue.

[image]

Comment: which is the off-angle?

Comment: The cone is not pointed straight down, 90degrees to the tangent of the Earth. Instead it is slewed a bit to theta...or (90 - theta), or however you want to think about those angles.

Comment: I wonder whether this has a nice analytic solution. Please [edit] the question to tell us why  you want to know.

Comment: This problem is unlikely to have anything to do with "calculus-of-variations". It is not related to "vector analysis" as I know it, neither. So I just removed those two tags. In case it turns out they are related, we can add them anyway.

Comment: Are you assuming a circular base? If you were to cut the cone parallel to the short leg of the triangle in the image, what shape would the new face have?

Comment: Fix the height of the cone to $H=h+r$, and place the vertex at $(0,0,H)$. You can then parameterize the cone by something like$$\vec v(R,\theta) = \langle R(a-\alpha_\phi \cos(\theta)), R(b-\alpha_\phi \sin(\theta)), (1-R)H\rangle, \qquad (R,\theta)\in[0,1]\times[0,2\pi]$$ $a,b$ give some indication of where the central axis of the cone meets the plane $z=0$ (when $R=1$), and $\alpha_\phi$ is the radius of the circular base. The subscript denotes dependence on $\phi$. The next step would be to find a parametric equation for the intersection of $\vec v$ and the sphere...

Comment: @user170231 good, then upload an orderly line of ideas into a response

Comment: Even calculating the projection as drawn will be quite complicated. Depending on the given angles some part, or all, of the cone will miss the earth and the projection calculation becomes even more complicated. I wonder if you ever get further than a set of equations that needs to be solved numerically.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an answer, but I got interested in the problem so I thought I might share a couple of pictures I drew with Mathematica.

Fix some cartesian coordinate system in $\mathbb{R}^3$, centered at the center of the sphere. After some rotations, you can assume that the satellite is looking down a line parallel to the $z$-axis and perpendicular to the $x,y$-plane. I will call $\vartheta$ the angle between this line and the segment joining the satellite with the center of the sphere, this is $\pi/2$ minus the original $\vartheta$ of the question. So $\vartheta$ and the height $h$ give us the position $v$ of the satellite, while its "view cone" has amplitude $\varphi$.

A point $p$ on the sphere can be seen from the satellite if and only if these two conditions hold:

1. the vectors $p-v$ and $(0,0,-1)$ must form an angle smaller than $\varphi$;
2. the point $p$ is not "over the orizon" with respect to $v$, this is equivalent to saying that the distance between $p$ and $v$ should be less than $\sqrt{(r+h)^2-r^2}$, where $r$ is the radius of the sphere.

With this in place, now it is quite easy to draw a picture of the viewed area. I will leave the Mathematica code below if you want to play around a bit.

As for the area, I have just been able to compute some values. I do not know if it admits an analytic expression, this would be interesting! Anyway, I assume that $r=1$, $\varphi=\pi/6$ and $h=0.5$, and see how the area changes when the "tilting" $\vartheta$ becomes more pronounced, from $0$ to $1$ radians. I think there should be an analytic expression for the value of $\vartheta$ which realizes the maximal area, it would be interesting to see!

Fig.1 : the satellite is at the tip of the cone, which represents its "field of view" (it should be infinitely tall, but it made for an ugly picture). The meshed yellow region is the part of the surface which can be seen from the satellite.

Fig.2 : Area on vertical axis, $\vartheta$ on the horizontal one, for $\varphi=\pi/6$ and $h=r/2$, $r=1$.

[image: the satellite is at the tip of the cone, which represents its "field of view" (it should be infinitely tall, but it made for an ugly picture). The meshed yellow region is the part of the surface which can be seen from the satellite.]

[[image: Area on vertical axis, <span class=]$\vartheta$ on the horizontal one, for $\varphi=\pi/6$ and $h=r/2$, $r=1$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHp5S.jpg)

Some Mathematica code to draw the viewed area:

```
vert[h_, \[Theta]_] := {0, (1 + h)*Sin[\[Theta]], (1 + h)*Cos[\[Theta]]}
c0[h_, \[Theta]_] := {0, (1 + h)*Sin[\[Theta]], 0}
angle[h_, \[Theta]_, u_, v_] := ArcCos[((1 + h)*Cos[\[Theta]] - Sin[v])/Sqrt[Abs[Cos[u]*Cos[v]]^2 + (-((1 + h)*Cos[\[Theta]]) + Sin[v])^2 + (Cos[v]*Sin[u] - (1 + h)*Sin[\[Theta]])^2]]
    Manipulate[Show[
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6], Sphere[], Green, Opacity[0.3], Cone[{c0[h, \[Theta]], vert[h, \[Theta]]},(1 + h)*Cos[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Phi]]]}, Boxed -> False],
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[v]*Cos[u], Cos[v]*Sin[u], Sin[v]},{u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2*Pi}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, angle[h, \[Theta], u, v] <= \[Phi] && Norm[{Cos[v]*Cos[u], Cos[v]*Sin[u], Sin[v]} - vert[h, \[Theta]]]^2 <= h^2 + 2*h], PlotPoints -> 100]],{{h, 0.3}, 0, 1}, {{\[Theta], Pi/4}, 0, Pi/2}, {{\[Phi], Pi/4}, 0, Pi/2}]
```

Some Mathematica code to compute the area (not particularly efficient):

```
    vert[h_, \[Theta]_] := {0, (1 + h)*Sin[\[Theta]], (1 + h)*Cos[\[Theta]]}
ViewedArea[h_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && ArcCos[(-z + (1 + h)*Cos[\[Theta]])/Sqrt[x^2 + (z - (1 + h)*Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (y - (1 + h)*Sin[\[Theta]])^2]] <= \[Phi] && 
    Norm[{x, y, z} - vert[h, \[Theta]]]^2 <= h^2 + 2*h, {x, y, z}]
```

Comment: how do you do that the green cone only projects **only over the sphere**, that is, with out leaving out in space?

Comment: @janmarqz if I understand the question correctly, the answer is that it might well be that for some combinations of $h$, $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$ the "cone of view" does not intersect the sphere at all. I guess this is precisely the typical situation for the Hubble telescope: in its case, $\vartheta$ is chosen so that it looks "away from Earth". If you play around with the above code you will see plenty of situation where the "viewed surface" vanishes.

Comment: please tell me if I misinterpreted you question, this might very well be the case

Comment: Ok, playing with your code I reached the configuration of the OP.